# Why does the Ubuntu docker base image only take 89 MB?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-image

In the Docker in Practice book, it explains that the todoapp that they create is layered on top of the `node` image, which is layered on top of `ubtunu` image (see image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRykU.png)). Why is the Ubuntu docker base image shown to take up only 89 MB, when in comparison a production OS install of Ubuntu takes approximately 10 times that much space?

Comment: Different, *much* smaller packageset. That said, this isn't really a question about writing code; consider [unix.se] rather than Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read [the ubuntu Dockerfile](https://github.com/tianon/docker-brew-ubuntu-core/blob/185c5e23efaa8c7c857683e6dcf4d886acda3cba/bionic/Dockerfile), you'll see that it's based on a tarball from https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/.

If you inspect the images at https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/minimal/releases/bionic/release/, you'll see that 75MB is typical compressed size.

---

To explain *why* this is so -- the `minimal` packageset is listed at https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/ubuntu-minimal. You'll see that it's a very small list -- no GUI, no development tools, no optional servers or services (as the expectation is that those will be installed later).

Comment: Note that this answer is marked Community Wiki: Since I don't believe the question is on-topic here, I'm not accepting any reputation linked to the answer, and others are free to edit it.